# Connecting RaspberryPi with android by bluetooth

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, bluetooth

I have to connect the rpi with android and send wifi config file. but there are 3 problems.

First: I have to connect only form android

Second: I don't have internet on rpi. I have it only at the beginning and when I send the config file. So I can send scripts by ssh only once. I mean in final version.

third: I have to do it by android app

I don't know how to even start.

Comment: Where those restrictions come from?

Comment: generally form project. for example: I'm doing android app and web site to control aquarium lamp. I need ssh so I have to had wifi connection.the only way, in my opinion, to connect rpi to wifi, is sending wifi config file and the only solution I can see is to send it by bluetooth.